# How do I set the phonegap-version in my configure.xml file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I want to use the latest version of cordova ( cli-8.0.0 ) how do I specify this in the config.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your config.xml

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If that helped, can you accept and upvote the answer?